# for some reallly odd reason css doesen't apply

Tags: css, python-3.x, flask

I am currently writing a program that makes you go to a website without actually going to the website
but for some odd reason CSS just doesn't work

```py
from flask import Flask, request, session, Response
import random
import requests
import string
from tld import get_tld
import json
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'fjwefjwefjwe'
urls = {}

def turn_headers_to_dict(headers):
    return {"User-Agent":headers["User-Agent"]}
def generatetoken(l):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for i in range(l))

@app.errorhandler(404)
def gotowebsite(error):
    global urls
    print(urls)
    if not session.get('computer_id'):

        session['computer_id'] = generatetoken(100)
        urls[session['computer_id']]="https://www.google.com"
    else:
        print(session['computer_id'])
    print(urls)
    site = urls[session['computer_id']] + request.full_path
    print(site)
    header = turn_headers_to_dict(request.headers)
    if request.method == "GET":
        a= requests.get(site, headers=header)
    else:
        a =  requests.post(site,headers=header, data=request.form)
    return Response(a.content
    , mimetype="text/plain")
@app.route('/')
def index():
    global urls
    print(urls)
    print(session.get('computer_id'))
    if not session.get('computer_id'):
        print("doing")
        session['computer_id'] = generatetoken(100)
        urls[session['computer_id']]="https://www.google.com"

    else:
        try:
            urls[session['computer_id']]
        except:
            session['computer_id'] = generatetoken(100)
            urls[session['computer_id']]="https://www.google.com"
        print(session['computer_id'])
    print(urls)
    site = urls[session['computer_id']]
    print(site)
    header = turn_headers_to_dict(request.headers)
    a = requests.get(site, headers=header)

    return a.content

@app.route("/change/<url>")
def change(url):
    try:
        session['computer_id'] = generatetoken(100)
        urls.update({session['computer_id']:"https://"+url})
        print(urls)
        return "ok"
    except:
        return "error"
    
app.run()
```

i expected for it to be working flawlessly but for some reason CSS DOESENT WORK!
WHYYYYY??? even JS works and i forgot to mention when i tweak the CSS a little bit IT STARTS TO WORK

Comment: If you make changes and it works, what isn't working? Please elaborate not in all caps what defines "not working"

Comment: wild guess, you are checking the session which requires cookies but static resource requests are often made w/o cookies because it lacks the SameSite attribute